# Dockerfile Nginx no muestra mi página

Tags: php, docker, nginx, lamp

presento mi problema, estoy haciendo una pila LEMP, no tengo mucho conocimiento en **Docker**, pero por lo que se, se que puedo construir una imagen desde el Dockerfile y puedo hacerlo correr con el comando "sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx". Cuando hice la instalación normal, sin docker, funcionaba perfectamente, mostraba mi **index**, pero ahora desde **Docker** no.

Os enseño mi Dockerfile:

```
    # Usamos de base la imagen de Nginx oficial
    FROM nginx:latest

    # Actualizamos e instalamos los programas necesarios
    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y nginx && \
        apt-get install -y php7.4-fpm php-mysql

    # COPIAMOS LOS ARCHIVOS DE CONFIG
    # Añadimos OpenSSH a ufw
    COPY ./files/openssh-server /etc/ufw/applications.d/openssh-server
    # Creamos donde vamos a tener la página web
    COPY ./files/proyecto_educados/. /var/www/html
    # Creamos el fichero de configuración
    COPY ./files/proyecto_educadosCONF /etc/nginx/sites-available/proyecto_educados

    # Damos permisos
    RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/proyecto_educados
    RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/proyecto_educados

    # Verificar si el directorio existe y crearlo si es necesario
    RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

    # Verificar y crear enlaces
    RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ && \
        ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/proyecto_educados /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

    RUN unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

    # Exponemos el puerto que usará
    EXPOSE 80
```

Como hago el **Dockerfile** desde nginx, hago los **COPY** de los ficheros y de la carpeta donde tengo toda la página web.

**OpenSSH**:

```
[OpenSSH]
        title=OpenSSH
        description=Secure shell server (sshd)
        ports=22/tcp
```

**proyecto_educadosCONF**:

```
        server {
        listen 80;
        server_name proyecto_educados www.proyecto_educados;
        root /var/www/html/proyecto_educados;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }
```

Y por si os interesa el copy de **proyecto_educados**, es decir la carpeta donde va toda mi página es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os doy las gracias de antemano, además si sabéis como añadir php correctamente porque no lo hace bien.

Comment: Si ya tienes corriendo un contenedor a partir del dockerfile, puedes correr `docker run -it tu_contenedor bash` y chismear por dentro cómo quedó esa configuración, a ver qué falta

Comment: He usado docker exec -it nginx bash y he visto todo, por lo que veo parece correcto, en /var/www/html están los ficheros de la página, el de configuración también está correcto, y sigue sin mostrarme mi index.

Comment: Ves algo en los logs que genera nginx allá adentro? Si haces una petición al index o algo, qué sale?

Comment: Funciona a ratos, he conseguido que funcione pero en un enlace .php en vez de redireccionar, lo descarga. En cuanto a tu pregunta @Alfabravo, no se respondertela.